# Is white space allowed betwee mime header field-name and ':' separator

Tags: http, header, whitespace, mime

Within a mime header, is white space allowed between the header field-name and ':' separator? For example, are:

```
Content-Type: <value>
```

and

```
Content-Type  : <value>
```

equivalent?

Also, can you please provide a pointer to the mime standard where this is described? I checked a few but did not find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't entirely clear whether it is or is not allowed, by the standard. However, implementations vary in how they handle whitespace between header field names and the colon. I would highly recommend avoiding whitespace there if you can.

The [RFC for reference](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt). [This somewhat old article discusses the issue for HTTP headers](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0822.txt), a similar standard.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I'm parsing messages from a server, so I guess it would be wise to allow for whitespace.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer the document. It clearly states that whitespace is allowed.
**3.1.4.  STRUCTURED FIELD BODIES

        To aid in the creation and reading of structured  fields,  the
        free  insertion   of linear-white-space (which permits folding
        by inclusion of CRLFs)  is  allowed  between  lexical  tokens.**

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what you mean by 'allowed'. RFCs [2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822) (which obsoleted the 1982 RFC822) and [5322](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322) (which obsoleted 2822) specifically forbid the insertion of WS between the field name and the colon (these are not 'MIME' standards, BTW). Note that `:` is not a token, and is only referenced as part of a field name, for example:

```
from = "From:" mailbox-list CRLF
```

However, the ancient RFC822 *did* allow space here, and the newer RFCs state that the obsolete syntax "MUST be accepted and parsed by a conformant receiver". The obsolete `From:` header definition, for example, was

```
obs-from = "From" *WSP ":" mailbox-list CRLF
```

Section 4 covers the obsolete syntax. I don't actually allow obsolete syntax in my own receiver, and I've never had a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If the question is about the HTTP then the answer is "no, not allowed". See http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p1-messaging-21.html#rfc.section.3.2